# Create new Pandas Dataframe from observations which meets specific criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have two original dataframes.
One contains limits: `df_limits`

```
           feat_1   feat_2  feat_3  
target       12       9       90    
UL           15       10      120   
LL           9        8       60
```

where target is ideal value,
UL - upper limit,
LL - lower limit

And another one original data: `df_to_check`

```
ID          feat_1  feat_2  feat_3  
123         12.5    9.6     100 
456         18      3       100
789         9       11      100
```

I'm creating a function which desired output is get ID and features which are below or above the threshold (limits from first Dataframe) Till now I'm able to recognise which features are out of limits but I'm getting full output of original Dataframe...

```
def table(df_limits, df_to_check, column):
    
    UL = df_limits[column].loc['target'] + df_limits[column].loc['UL']
    LL = df_limits[column].loc['target'] + df_limits[column].loc['LL']
    
    UL_index = df_to_check.loc[df_to_check[column] > UL].index
    LL_index = df_to_check.loc[df_to_check[column] < LL].index
    
    if UL_index is not None:
        above_limit = {'ID': df_to_check['ID'],
                       'column': df_to_check[column],
                       'target':  df_limits[column].loc['target']}
        
    return pd.DataFrame(above_limit)
```

What I should change so my desired output would be:
(showing only ID and column where observations are out of limit)

The best if it would show also how many percent of original value is deviate from ideal value `target` (I would be glad for advices how to add such a column)

```
ID     column    target    value    deviate(%)
456    feat_1    12        18       50
456    feat_2    9         3        ...
789    feat_2    9         11       ...
```

Now after running this function its returning whole dataset because statement says if not null... which is not null... I understand why I have this issue but I don't know how to change it

Issue is with statement `if UL_index is not None:` since it returning whole dataset and I'm looking for way how to replace this part

Comment: Do you mean that target = ideal value, UL and LL mean upper limit and lower limit? Ie if a value is outside of these bounds it is invalid / to be rejected etc for some reason? If that's the case, it would be useful to amend your original question to make this clearer.

You should also provide some test data. Yours is not a minimum, reproducible example; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: First question - yes and I already changed my question. This what happening with values out of bounds is not what is interesting for us right now. I just want return them from a function and see how much they are deviate from target... I will try to improve question as you suggested

Comment: Also I highlighted that I have to change only one line of code (last sentence) to not get original Dataframe but only values out of bonds :)

Comment: One more thing that's not clear to me: are you looking at each column (feature) independently? Ie do you want to know how many IDs have all features which are all within the range? What happens if, for a given id, feature 1 is within the range but feature 2 isn't? How do you treat that?

Comment: Look at the desired output. Yes Im checking every feature separately since they have different ranges. If in ID:123 feat1 and featx is out of range I want have it in my new table... I just simply want to see all observations out of range and thing that it have to be corrected is just `if UL_index is not None:` bc this returns whole original dataset :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach

- reshape
- merge
- calculate

```
new_df = (df_to_check.set_index("ID").unstack().reset_index()
 .rename(columns={"level_0":"column",0:"value"})
 .merge(df_limits.T, left_on="column", right_index=True)
 .assign(deviate=lambda dfa: (dfa.value-dfa.target)/dfa.target)
)
```

| column | ID | value | target | UL | LL | deviate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| feat_1 | 123 | 12.5 | 12 | 15 | 9 | 0.0416667 |
| feat_1 | 456 | 18 | 12 | 15 | 9 | 0.5 |
| feat_1 | 789 | 9 | 12 | 15 | 9 | -0.25 |
| feat_2 | 123 | 9.6 | 9 | 10 | 8 | 0.0666667 |
| feat_2 | 456 | 3 | 9 | 10 | 8 | -0.666667 |
| feat_2 | 789 | 11 | 9 | 10 | 8 | 0.222222 |
| feat_3 | 123 | 100 | 90 | 120 | 60 | 0.111111 |
| feat_3 | 456 | 100 | 90 | 120 | 60 | 0.111111 |
| feat_3 | 789 | 100 | 90 | 120 | 60 | 0.111111 |

Comment: Very elegant answer and certainly more 'pythonic' than mine! Coming from a SQL background I prefer to think in terms of normalised tables and joins, but that's subjective. Also, one thing newbies should be aware of is that chaning methods this way can be very powerful but makes your code harder to debug.

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous I'm from a similar background,  many years of SQL.  That's the reason I think a) project/join to calculation model b) calculate c) project to output model.  The way I do chained pipelines makes it easy to comment out last parts so it's easier to re-understand building blocks in a jupyter notebook ....

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have not provided a reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example because you have not shared the code which produces the two initial dataframes. Next time you ask a question, please keep it in mind, Without those, I made a toy example with my own (random) data.

I start by unpivoting what you call dataframe_to_check: that's because, if you want to check each feature independently, then that dataframe is not normalised (you might want to look up what database normalisation means).

The next step is a left outer join between the unpivoted dataframe you want to check and the (transposed) dataframe with the limits.

Once you have that, you can easily calculate whether a row is within the range, the deviation between value and target, etc, and you can of course group this however you want.

My code is below. It should be easy enough to customise it to your case.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df_limits = pd.DataFrame(index =['min val','max val','target'])

df_limits['a']=[2,4,3]
df_limits['b']=[3,5,4.5]


df =pd.DataFrame(columns = df_limits.columns, data =np.random.rand(100,2)*6 )

df_unpiv = pd.melt( df.reset_index().rename(columns ={'index':'id'}), id_vars='id', var_name ='feature', value_name = 'value' )

# I reset the index because I couldn't get a join on a column and index, but there is probably a better way to do it
df_joined = pd.merge( df_unpiv, df_limits.transpose().reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'feature'}), how='left', on ='feature' )
df_joined['abs diff from target'] = abs( df_joined['value'] - df_joined['target'] )

df_joined['outside range'] =  (df_joined['value'] < df_joined['min val'] ) | (df_joined['value'] > df_joined['max val'])
    
df_outside_range = df_joined.query(" `outside range` == True "  )
df_inside_range = df_joined.query(" `outside range` == False "  )
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved my issue maybe in bit clumsy way but it works as desired...
If someone have better answer I will still appreciate:

Example how to get only observations above limits, to have both just concatenate observation from UL_index and LL_index

```
def table(df_limits,df_to_check,column):
    
    above_limit = []
    df_above_limit = pd.DataFrame()
    
    UL = df_limits[column].loc['target'] + df_limits[column].loc['UL']
    LL = df_limits[column].loc['target'] + df_limits[column].loc['LL']
    
    UL_index = df_to_check.loc[df_to_check[column] > UL].index
    LL_index = df_to_check.loc[df_to_check[column] < LL].index
    
    df_to_check_UL = df_to_check.loc[UL_index]
    df_to_check_LL = df_to_check.loc[LL_index]
    
    above_limit = {
                    'ID': df_to_check_UL['ID'],
                    'feature value': df_to_check[column],
                    'target':  df_limits[column].loc['target']
    }
        
    df_above_limit = pd.DataFrame(above_limit, index = df_to_check_UL.index)
        
    return df_above_limit
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't seem like the most elegant solution. Is this a function you apply to each column? If so, it is going to be much slower than my solution, which is all based on vectorised code. For very small datasets the difference will be small, but for large ones it can be meaningful.

Comment: Yes, we posted at the same minute. You're right thanks for you solution, unfortunately I don't have access even to full data that's why I coudnt provide the code which produces initial datafrmaes.

Comment: You don't need to share the exact same data. In fact, in many cases such data is confidential and sharing it would be a crime. However, you can generalise your problem and come up with a toy example with some data you have made up. Eg you don't know how to group the confidential financial data of your company, but you can come up with a toy example on how many apples are sold in London or New York which has the same data structure. This is the point of this link, which, again, I urge you to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example